# ERROR: Socket /var/run/openvswitch/ovnnb_db.sock not found

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68001501/error-opt-stack-devstack-lib-neutron-plugins-ovn-agent174-socket) link  about the problem mentioned in topic, but because it is patched in new version of openstack, it does not work.
Any ideas guys?
Cheers